# Filtering dataframe based on multiple conditions using boolean logic

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to filter a dataframe based on the following conditions, if `end_date` is `Nan` OR if the `end_date` is greater than the current date.
How exactly can I do this?
I'm using the following code, I am aware the `| and &` operators are series operators.

```
end_series = ((~df.end_date.notna()) | (df.end_date > datetime.datetime.utcnow().date()))
new_df = df[(df.column1 > 0)  &  end_series].copy()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
current_date = pd.to_datetime("today").date()
new_df = df.query("end_date.isna() or (end_date > @current_date) and column1 > 0")
```